# Safe way to write a PDO query

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Which of these two is the safe method to write a query?

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("UPDATE tableName SET fieldName = 0");
```

OR

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("UPDATE tableName SET fieldName = :parameter");
$stmt-> bindValue(':parameter', 0);
```

I know the 2nd method is way best and I use it whenever I use a `$variable` in `bindValue`. But here, I need to use a known integer `0`. So, the first process seemed easier as I did not had to write another `bindValue` statement. But, is it safe?

Comment: this would be useful , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php

Comment: If the value is a constant Vale the first Statement is safe

Comment: are you sure @Jens?

Comment: If your values are constant, then it is okay to include them in the query

Comment: are you sure too? @CarlJan

Comment: @ShubhamJha Yes i am

Comment: parameterized queries are used for dynamic values, like values that came from user inputs

Comment: Since a user can't change or have any control over a hardcoded value then, yes, the first example is file :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your questions I'd say that you'll definitely benefit from reading the [PDO tutorial](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#query) I wrote, which says:

> There are two ways to run a query in PDO. If no variables are going to be used in the query, you can use the `PDO::query()` method.

and

> if at least one variable is going to be used in the query, you have to substitute it with a placeholder, then prepare your query, and then execute it, passing variables separately.

So now you can tell that for this particular query you can use the `query()` method instead of prepare/execute

```
$stmt = $pdo->query("UPDATE tableName SET fieldName = 0");
```

as there is no variables to be used and this no danger at all